# Stripe billing with same price as form

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

So I wish to bill customers (who are not users) the same amount as what is displayed in the stripe form

```
<form action="/charge" method="POST">
                 {!! csrf_field() !!}
                  <script
                    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                    data-key="pk_test_key"
                    data-amount="{{ $note->price*100 }}"
                    data-name="Hello World"
                    data-description="{{$note->title}}"
                    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
                    data-locale="auto"
                    data-currency="aud">
                  </script>
                </form>
```

In the form the price displayed is the price listed in the relevant note model * 100. I would like the customer to actually be billed this value, it will change depending upon the note.

Here is my server billing

```
public function charge()
{
    // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    // See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_key");

    // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

    // Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    try {
      $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => 100, // amount in cents, again
        "currency" => "aud",
        "source" => $token,
        "description" => "Example charge"
        ));
    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
      // The card has been declined
    }

    return 'payment succesful';
}
```

I need to set the "amount" equal to the note value.

Otherwise, payment is going through on my cashier test account and mostly everything else needs to be working.

The customers are not registered users though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount needs to be something that you calculate server side, otherwise people can just modify the DOM and pass whatever amount they would like.

Instead, store the `id` in the cache on the server side, and pass the `note` in as a dependency to the `charge` function, then compare the 2.

```
/**
 * Assuming name of "view" page
 */
public function checkout(Note $note) 
{
    /**
     * Always forget this on each page load, so we can switch seamlessly between Notes.
     */
    Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::forget('nid')->put('nid', $note->id);
}
```

Don't forget to modify the `charge` route to include the new reference to our `Note` dependency

```
route::post('charge/{note}', 'Controller@charge')->name('charge');
```

Make sure to update your form to pass the `note` as well

```
<form action="{{route('charge', $note)}}" method="POST">
```

**sidenote** I like named routes, but it's not required.

Then when you're processing the request, compare the `$nid` and the `$note->id`

```
public function charge(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, Note $note)
{
    $nid = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::get('nid');

    // id's match, no sneaky stuff. safe to use $note->price now
    if ($nid === $note->id) {
        //now we can process our payment.
        // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
        // See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_key");

        // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
        $token = $request->get('stripeToken');

        // Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
        try {
            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                "amount" => number_format($note->price, 0, '', ''), // amount in cents, again
                "currency" => "aud",
                "source" => $token,
                "description" => "Example charge"
            ));
        } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
            // The card has been declined
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: @DanielPahor You can, but I avoid using the `session` and take advantage of `redis` for my cache. I like the control and security a bit more. Take my opinion with a grain of salt, however.